# "Unrecognized USB device" SATA-to-USB? Forceably assign driver to device?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, usb-to-sata

Every time I plug this thing in, regardless of what harddrive I use, it says "unrecognized USB device" on this system; however, the device works on other win 7 systems.  Why does this PC hate my SATA-to-HDD?  I need to offload some files before my harddrive explodes.

Device info:
Sabrent USB-DSC9

### May help?

Trying to get the "mass storage usb device" driver to apply to this device by manual override.  If there's a way to do that, please post it?

### What actually happens

On the other system, most of the HDD's load as "removable device" with no data.  One harddrive works properly.  When I plug the properly-working device into this machine (ProBook 6550b), I get a "Removable Disk" with no data.  The other two HDD's on this machine give me a "Unrecognized USB device" error.  *One of the two HDD's that work on neither machine, showing no data, works internally on my tower.*

### Very poor workaround

Use a thumb drive, external hdd, or phone to move files off of the afflicted PC and onto the external hdd as the external hdd is plugged in to another  machine.

Comment: The PC only supports USB 2.0, but it's a USB 3.0 device: sabrent USB-DSC9.

Comment: Please be kind to others.  My requests were not unreasonable.  My vote was reversed.  *I find that if I don't vote, problems with questions, are never addressed.*  Voting is extremely helpful to improve the quality of a question or answer.  It isn't going away so adapt how you ask questions to the community.

Comment: Contact Sabrent about the issue...http://sabrent.com/support/